# chrome.tabs.sendMessage when tab is not focused

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I have a chrome extension that sends and receives messages back and forth between content and background scripts.

Everything works fine with `chrome.runtime`, but I am using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` to send messages to the content scripts using something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "stuff"}, function(response) { });
});
```

The extension runs only on a few specific urls, and when that code executes while im on a different tab than the one the extension is running on, or in the background inspect view, it doesn't work.

How can I make it work even when tab is active/focused at the moment the code run?

Comment: do you wanna send the message to all tabs???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 console.log(sender.tab.id);
});
```

Using `sender.tab.id` instead of `tabs[0].id` seems to do the job

Comment: How to do it for "n"th tab?